# Get key of IntegrityError in django bulk_create

Tags: python, django, bulkinsert

I am trying to do a Model.objects.bulk_create(bulk_objects) in django, I am expecting IntegrityError's at times but I would like get the objects details that has caused the exception.

```
try:
        # bulk_objects contains ~70k items
        Auction.objects.bulk_create(bulk_objects)
except IntegrityError as e:
        print(str(e.__cause__))
        msg = str(e.__cause__)
        match = re.search('(?!\()\d+(?=\))', msg)
        print(match.group(0)) # prints 123865 in this case
```

this throws the exception

```
insert or update on table "auction_table" violates foreign key constraint"my_constraint"
DETAIL:  Key (item_id)=(123865) is not present in table "item_table".
```

This is fine and I expect this, I am wanting to get the item_id that has caused the exception, in this case the item_id of 123865.

Is there a way of doing this without doing some regex on the string or iterating over the bulk_objects?

Was just hoping to get it directly from the error, otherwise I will continue with the regex approach

Comment: there is no way to get key directly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exception raised when the relational integrity of the database is affected, e.g. a foreign key check fails, duplicate key, etc... 
So check if there are any duplicate entries, or any foreign key constraint of Database is failing.

```
    def bulk_create(self, objs, batch_size=None):
    """
    Inserts each of the instances into the database. This does *not* call
    save() on each of the instances, does not send any pre/post save
    signals, and does not set the primary key attribute if it is an
    autoincrement field (except if features.can_return_ids_from_bulk_insert=True).
    Multi-table models are not supported.
    """
```

According to docs `bulk_create()` will not support Multi-table models. So you have to create a batch explicitly then  send that batch to `bulk_create()`. While creating that batch you can verify such things.
You can check how to create a batch [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

Comment: I know why the exception is being raised, thats not the problem I've got. What I am after is the particular object that has caused the exception, it could be 1 of 70k+ objects.I was hoping I could extract it from the error raised but can't figure that part out. Currently I am grabbing the objects details from the string `e.__cause__` with regex

Comment: `Key (item_id)=(123865) is not present in table "item_table".` so the `item_id=123865` is not there in `item_table` so it is giving you error, you can sort out objects which have item_id's  as 123865 cause they are causing Error.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware that my `item_table` is lacking an item with the id of 123865, I can fix that manually. I am asking if there is a way to programmatically get the item id that causes the error, this way I can handle it accordingly within the program instead of manually reading error logs and making manual changes. I am getting the id using regex, I was just wondering if there was another way to do so.